# Animated stroke-dashoffset on iOS

Tags: css, animation, svg

So, I have this SVG logo animated by increasing the `stroke-dashoffset` value

```css
svg {
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 150px;
}

.cls-1,
.cls-2 {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#a9a9a9;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-width:10px;
}

.cls-1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 496;
  stroke-dashoffset: -496;
  animation: firstLine 2s ease-out 0s infinite normal;
}

.cls-2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 458;
  stroke-dashoffset: -458;
  animation: secondLine 2s ease-out 0s infinite normal;
}

@keyframes firstLine {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: -496; }
  40% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
  60% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
  85% { stroke-dashoffset: 496; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 496; }
}

@keyframes secondLine {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: -458; }
  45% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
  60% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
  90% { stroke-dashoffset: 458; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 458; }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200.17 135"><path class="cls-1" d="M132.67,28.44a39.06,39.06,0,0,1,0,78.12H113.22V59.11A54.11,54.11,0,0,0,5,59.11v57.35a13.54,13.54,0,0,0,27.08,0v-9.9h27"/><path class="cls-2" d="M113.63,5h19a62.5,62.5,0,0,1,0,125H102.44a16.29,16.29,0,0,1-16.3-16.29V59.11a27,27,0,0,0-54.06,0V79.89h27"/></svg>
```

When opened on desktop browser, everything is fine. Same for Android. But on iOS, the animation is going so wrong. Is there some iOS specific bug `stroke-dashoffset` that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Safari does not support negative numbers as stroke-dashoffset values. This is a longstanding bug and other UAs have no issue with negative numbers.

Comment: @RobertLongson Oh whow, I was expecting a bug, but not something like that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been looking for a solution for a long time how to replace negative stroke-dashoffset values with positive values in order to circumvent the restrictions that safari imposes.

Explanations are given for animating one line. For the second line, the calculation is similar.

- The total length of the line is `496 px`; therefore, the value of
  `stroke-dashoffset = "496"`completely hides the line.
- With double value `stroke-dashoffset ="992"` line is drawn
- With triple value `stroke-dashoffset =" 1488 "`, the line is erased
  again

### CSS solution

```css
svg {
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 150px;
}

.cls-1,
.cls-2 {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#a9a9a9;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-width:10px;
}
.cls-1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 496;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: firstLine 2s ease-out 0s infinite normal;
}

.cls-2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 458;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: secondLine 2s ease-out 0s infinite normal;
}

@keyframes firstLine {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: 496; }
  40% { stroke-dashoffset: 992; }
  60% { stroke-dashoffset: 992; }
  85% { stroke-dashoffset: 1488; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 1488; }
}

@keyframes secondLine {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: 458; }
  45% { stroke-dashoffset: 916; }
  60% { stroke-dashoffset: 916; }
  90% { stroke-dashoffset: 1374; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 1374; }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200.17 135">
<path class="cls-1 " d="M132.67,28.44a39.06,39.06,0,0,1,0,78.12H113.22V59.11A54.11,54.11,0,0,0,5,59.11v57.35a13.54,13.54,0,0,0,27.08,0v-9.9h27" >
</path>
  <path class="cls-2" d="M113.63,5h19a62.5,62.5,0,0,1,0,125H102.44a16.29,16.29,0,0,1-16.3-16.29V59.11a27,27,0,0,0-54.06,0V79.89h27" > 
</path>
 
</svg>
```

**Option with a shadow around the logo**

Add shadow

```
<defs>
        <filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="8" stdDeviation="4"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
```

```css
body {
background: rgb(144,210,152);
background: linear-gradient(286deg, rgba(144,210,152,1) 29%, rgba(236,234,154,1) 69%);
}
svg {
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 150px;
}

.cls-1,
.cls-2 {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#a9a9a9;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-width:10px;
  filter:url(#shadow);
}
.cls-1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 496;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: firstLine 4s ease-out 0s infinite normal;
}

.cls-2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 458;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: secondLine 4s ease-out 0s infinite normal;
}

@keyframes firstLine {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: 496; }
  40% { stroke-dashoffset: 992; }
  60% { stroke-dashoffset: 992; }
  85% { stroke-dashoffset: 1488; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 1488; }
}

@keyframes secondLine {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: 458; }
  45% { stroke-dashoffset: 916; }
  60% { stroke-dashoffset: 916; }
  90% { stroke-dashoffset: 1374; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 1374; }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 220.17 150">
<defs>
        <filter id="shadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feDropShadow dx="4" dy="8" stdDeviation="4"/>
        </filter>
    </defs> 
  
<path class="cls-1 " d="M132.67,28.44a39.06,39.06,0,0,1,0,78.12H113.22V59.11A54.11,54.11,0,0,0,5,59.11v57.35a13.54,13.54,0,0,0,27.08,0v-9.9h27" >
</path>
  <path class="cls-2" d="M113.63,5h19a62.5,62.5,0,0,1,0,125H102.44a16.29,16.29,0,0,1-16.3-16.29V59.11a27,27,0,0,0-54.06,0V79.89h27" > 
</path> 

</svg>
```

### SVG solution

```css
svg {
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 150px;
}

.cls-1,
.cls-2 {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#a9a9a9;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-width:10px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200.17 135">
<path class="cls-1 " d="M132.67,28.44a39.06,39.06,0,0,1,0,78.12H113.22V59.11A54.11,54.11,0,0,0,5,59.11v57.35a13.54,13.54,0,0,0,27.08,0v-9.9h27" stroke-dasharray="496,496" stroke-dashoffset="496">
  <animate id="an_offset"
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
 begin="0s"
 dur="3s"
 values="496;992;992;1488"
 fill="freeze"
 repeatCount="indefinite"  />
</path>
  <path class="cls-2" d="M113.63,5h19a62.5,62.5,0,0,1,0,125H102.44a16.29,16.29,0,0,1-16.3-16.29V59.11a27,27,0,0,0-54.06,0V79.89h27" stroke-dasharray="458,458" stroke-dashoffset="458"> 
    <animate id="an_offset2"
  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
  begin="0s"
  dur="3s"
  values="458;916;916;1374"
  fill="freeze"
  repeatCount="indefinite" />
</path>
 
</svg>
```

**Additional example**
  Drawing from each line from its midpoint

To implement the animation, change the parameters of the `stroke-dasharray` attribute

With a total line length of `496px`, half of it is` 248px

- since the values of the parameters in order mean:
  `0 - line`, `248 -   space` `0 - line`, `248 - space`.
  Therefore, writing `stroke-dasharray = "0,248 0,248"` will completely hide the line
- With `stroke-dasharray = "0,0 496,0"` the line will be fully visible.

```css
svg {
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 150px;
}

.cls-1,
.cls-2 {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#a9a9a9;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-width:10px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200.17 135">
<path class="cls-1 " d="M132.67,28.44a39.06,39.06,0,0,1,0,78.12H113.22V59.11A54.11,54.11,0,0,0,5,59.11v57.35a13.54,13.54,0,0,0,27.08,0v-9.9h27" stroke-dasharray="496,496" stroke-dashoffset="496">
  <animate id="an_array"
    attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
 begin="0s"
 dur="4s"
 values="0,248 0,248;0,0 496,0;0,0 496,0;0,248 0,248"
 fill="freeze"
 repeatCount="indefinite"  />
</path>
  <path class="cls-2" d="M113.63,5h19a62.5,62.5,0,0,1,0,125H102.44a16.29,16.29,0,0,1-16.3-16.29V59.11a27,27,0,0,0-54.06,0V79.89h27" stroke-dasharray="458,458" stroke-dashoffset="458"> 
    <animate id="an_array2"
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   begin="0s"
   dur="4s"
   values="0,229 0,229;0,0 458,0;0,0 458,0;0,229 0,229"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</path>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, as I already close the question with my answer, I was not paying attention to notifications. My bad, fixing that, thanks :)

Comment: @Axiol Thanks for the interesting question. It was fun to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @RobertLongson, it's a Safari bug where is does not support negative values for `stroke-dashiffset`